# PHP: how to compare value of one array with value to other array in the loop

Tags: php

Trying to implement the following functionality.
There are lists of playlists that are created by the users themselves. If the user is logged in and is on the same page where the player is located with the song, you need to display a list of his own playlists and show that this song is already in his playlists.

List users playlists

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [playlist_id] => 1
            [title] => My firts playlist
            [user] => 20
            [date] => 2019-02-15 00:00:00
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [playlist_id] => 2
            [title] => My another playlist
            [user] => 20
            [date] => 2019-02-15 00:00:00
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [playlist_id] => 3
            [title] => My tested playlist
            [user] => 20
            [date] => 2019-02-15 00:00:00
        )

)
```

Array with all users song added of any playlists

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [playlist_id] => 2
            [song] => QhvUVlCt
            [user] => 20
            [date] => 2019-02-15 20:41:47
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [playlist_id] => 1
            [song] => QhvUVlCt
            [user] => 20
            [date] => 2019-02-16 13:17:11
        )

)
```

As can be seen from the second code, the song with the identifier 'QhvUVlCt' is in two playlists out of three users with the identifier '20'

It’s not difficult to display just playlists to the page, I use the foreach cycle

The difficulty is how to compare keys from two different arrays. For example, as in my example, two playlists (playlist_id = 1 and playlist_id = 2), in which this song already exists, output the mark "Already added to this playlist", and the rest (in my example, this playlist_id = 3) display the mark "Add to this playlist"

Output only playlist:

```
<?php foreach($playlists as $playlist): ?>
    <a href="#" class="playlists__link" data-action="playlist" data-id="<?php echo $playlist->playlist_id; ?>">
        <strong span class="playlists__title">
            <span class="playlists__icon"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></span>
            <?php echo $playlist->title; ?>
        </strong>
</a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And how to implement a comparison - I can not figure it out

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Care to show us what you have already tried?

Comment: @tshimkus, what do you mean

Comment: My mistake. I thought you were looking for songs that were not added to any user playlists, not per user. Disregard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should extract playlist ids from second array (`$songs`) with `array_column` for example:

```
$playlistIds = array_column($second_array, 'playlist_id');
```

Them iterate over `$playlists`:

```
foreach($playlists as $playlist):
    if (in_array($playlist->id, $playlistIds)) {
        // do one thing
    } else {
        // do another thing
    }
endforeach;
```

**Update** for `array_column`: as `array_column` can extract columns (not really columns, but properties) from **objects** since php7, you can use simple `foreach`:

```
$playlistIds = [];
foreach ($second_array as $song) {
    $playlistIds[] = $song->playlist_id;
}
```

And even a **faster** version will be:

```
$playlistIds = [];
foreach ($second_array as $song) {
    // here you set `playlist_id` as key
    $playlistIds[$song->playlist_id] = true;
}

foreach($playlists as $playlist):
    // `isset` is faster than `in_array`
    if (isset($playlistIds[$playlist->id])) {
        // do one thing
    } else {
        // do another thing
    }
endforeach;
```

Comment: Yes, this is almost what is needed, but what about the fact that the array element contains an object?

Comment: It doesn' matter. `$playlistIds` is plain __array__ of values.

Comment: But in this case, $playlistIds is empty and an error is thrown.

Comment: What error? Also - what is your php version?

Comment: Sorry, the mistake was on my part. But the essence does not change. The array is empty and in_array does not work. PHP 5.6

Comment: $playlistIds is plain array, but $second_array from your example it contains objects inside the array element

Comment: Updated my answer about `array_column`.

Comment: Awesome ... Thanks